# Ubuntu Server 16.04 VPN connection issue

Tags: server, 16.04, vpn

I'll try to make this as brief as possible while giving as many details as possible.

Here is the situation, I setup a IPSEC VPN on my core router for my WISP so I could log in remotely. Works beautifully on Windows 10 and my business partners iPhone and iPad.

I have a a homelab setup at my house and I wanted to leverage a VM to do SNMP traffic monitoring for the WISP network for all of the devices. Step one is to get the Linux VM, (Ubuntu Server 16.04 in this case) to connect to the VPN server. Step two will be actually configuring an SNMP monitoring program.

Doing some research, I located [this](http://www.jasonernst.com/2016/06/21/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu-16-04/) guide on how to setup StrongSwan as a client on Ubuntu server. A lot of other guides say to use OpenSwan but that has been depreciated/removed from the Server 16.04 repos.

Got that installed and partially working.
The good news is that the VPN will connect successfully. The bad news is that it doesn't seem to be creating the tunnel interface on Ubuntu.

So what am I missing here? I've been working on this for the last month and a half and I am out of ideas. A fresh pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the config files from my client setup. Sanitized:

/etc/ipsec.conf

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
# strictcrlpolicy=yes
# uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

conn %default
    ikelifetime=60m
    keylife=20m
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyingtries=1
    keyexchange=ikev1
    authby=secret
    esp=aes128-sha1
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!


conn AMVPN
    keyexchange=ikev1
    left=%defaultroute
    auto=add
    authby=secret
    type=transport
    leftprotoport=17/1701
    rightprotoport=17/1701
    # set this to the ip address of your vpn server
    right=IP
```

/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf

```
[lac AMVPN]
; your vpn server goes here
lns = IP
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
length bit = yes
```

And finnally /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-mschap-v2
noccp
noauth
idle 1800
mtu 1410
mru 1410
defaultroute
usepeerdns
debug
lock
connect-delay 5000
```

Again, let me know if you have any questions, comments, or suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Working with this for the last couple of days, I have narrowed down the issue.
It seems that the PPP interface is not being created.
Problem is, I have no idea why.